# How do I find yesterday's date

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery

I'm stuck on a query regarding dates in Big Query using SQL.
I have a table that consists of customer_id (int), date_purchase (date), sales (int).

The query is to find all customer_id and date_purchase with lower sales in comparison the the previous date_purchase (yesterday).

I've tried using the following statement:
`DATE_SUB(date_purchase,interval 1 day)`, however this also creates dates that don't exist in the database.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Including your query would be helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm doing this correctly, please see my sections of workings. I haven't been able to automatically identify the today and yesterday's dates without manually putting it in the code. Max(datepurchase) does not seem to work. Below are the parts I have. 

select id, revenue from

(SELECT id, datepurchase as today, revenue from SALES 
where datepurchase>='2022-05-29') t1

**NOT SURE WHAT GOES HERE**

 (SELECT id, datepurchase as yesterday, revenue from SALES
where datepurchase='2022-05-28' )t2
on t1.id=t2.id

where t1.revenue<t2.revenue

Answer (score 0):

In Bigquery you can directly use (date- 1) to get previous date.
Below is example
[image]